# Itext7 can it repair a pdf with errors like invalid operator,bad trailer dictionary and Name tree node missing required Limit

Tags: itext7

I am processing a file from a supplier and was getting errors.
Finally tracked it down using ghostscript

The file has issues - it it possible to open the file, fix the issues and save the file using Itext7 ?

I can do it with an external process with ghostscript but would prefer to no have an extra process running.

The supplier of the PDF is using an old version of itext with BIRT Report Engine

The following warnings were encountered at least once while processing this file:
invalid operator used in text block
bad trailer dictionary
Name tree node missing required Limits entry

**** This file had errors that were repaired or ignored.
**** The file was produced by:
**** >>>> iText 2.1.7 by 1T3XT <<<<
**** Please notify the author of the software that produced this
**** file that it does not conform to Adobe's published PDF
**** specification.

Comment: IText does not have an explicit repair api but as long as it can read the file at all, you can implement a repair tool with it. You will need to know, though, the list of possible errors you want to be able to repair.

Comment: I was able to create a blank pdf and merge the file with it. This removed two errors but left "invalid operator used in text block"  I can read text from file but have a add a try catch to get over the error